# Issue with SQL query (working with 3 tables)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook-wall

Currently I'm working on the Social Network. I decided to make friends relationship (like FB does) instead of following users (like TW does) and here come my problem.

So, I have 3 tables (Users, Posts, Friends).

[Friends Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtoWg.png)

[Post Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0PbA.png)

[Users Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9xYZ.png)

I would like to do it so that if the user has no friends (or just sent an invitation [friends_type == 1 in friends table]), only his posts are displayed.

My idea for this is: `SELECT * FROM users, posts, friends WHERE friends_status=4`, but when user has friends I would like to see posts from him and his friends.

And of course this is my SQL query I made: `SELECT * FROM posts, users, friends WHERE user_id=post_author AND friends_status=4 AND (friend_friendid=user_id OR friend_userid=user_id) ORDER BY post_id DESC`.

Basically, I want to achieve what Facebook has on the home page (never-ending timeline where you can scroll and scroll). My question is: How to build that query?

Comment: Could you pls clarify, what's your question?

Comment: First: Provide information about what is the issue , you got an error or what? Second: it seems your SQL query assumes another table structure than those you posted , i can't find posts_userid field in the images there is a field post_author

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, please use ANSI standard joins. Listing all of the tables in the `FROM` clause is both horrible and outdates by about 20 years...

Answer (score 0):

This is one method, using a subrequest to find friends :

```
select *
from posts
where post_author = {user_id}
   or post_author in
   (
     select friend_friendid from friends
     where friend_userid = {user_id}
       and friend_status != 1
   )
```